# Google Maps Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps, npm

I am trying to create a heatmap using JS and Google Maps API but I am getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <div class="group">
          <div class="subject">Radius <span id=radiusNum>21</span></div>
          <button onclick="changeRadius(true)">Up</button>
          <button onclick="changeRadius(false)">Down</button>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
          <div class="subject">Intensity <span id=intensityNum>200</span></div>
          <button onclick="changeIntensity(true)">Up</button>
          <button onclick="changeIntensity(false)">Down</button>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
          <div class="subject">Opacity <span id=opacityNum>.6</span></div>
          <button onclick="changeOpacity(true)">Up</button>
          <button onclick="changeOpacity(false)">Down</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      const maxI = 200, rad = 21, opac = .6;
      var map, heatmap;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        fetch('static/location.json', {headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'}
        })
            .then(function (response) {
              response.json().then(function (result) {

            let locations = result.locations.map((val) => {
              return new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitudeE7 * (10 ** -7), val.longitudeE7 * (10 ** -7));
            })

            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
              data: locations,
              map: map,
              maxIntensity: maxI,
              radius: rad,
              opacity: opac
            });
          });
        });
      }

      // Function to change the radius of data points on heatmap
      function changeRadius(bool) {
        const step = 3, min = 0, max = 50;
        let current = heatmap.get('radius');
        let newValue = toggleUpDown(bool, current, step, min, max);

        heatmap.set('radius', newValue);
        document.getElementById("radiusNum").innerText = newValue;
      };

      // Function to change the opacity of the heatmap
      function changeOpacity(bool) {
        const step = .2, min = 0, max = 1;
        let current = heatmap.get('opacity');
        let newValue = toggleUpDown(bool, current, step, min, max);
        let rounded = round(newValue, 1);

        heatmap.set('opacity', rounded);
        document.getElementById("opacityNum").innerText = rounded;
      }

      // Function to change maxIntensity of the heatmap
      function changeIntensity(bool) {
        const step = 25, min = 0, max = 1000;
        let current = heatmap.get('maxIntensity');
        let newValue = toggleUpDown(bool, current, step, min, max);

        heatmap.set('maxIntensity', newValue);
        document.getElementById("intensityNum").innerText = newValue;
      };

      // Changes our toggle values and keeps them within our min/max values
      function toggleUpDown(bool, current, step, min, max){
        if (bool && current >= max) return current;
        if (!bool && current <= min) return current;

        if (bool) return current + step;
        return current - step;
      }

      // Used to round the opacity toggle to one decimal place
      function round(value, precision) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
        return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=INTENTIONALLY_CHANGED_MY_KEY_HERE&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");
const app = express()

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000!'))
```

I have no clue why or what this error is. I looked up on google and it suggest that it could be because I am receiving html file instead of json but I am clearly using location.json file here.

I am using Windows 10, running the app on latest npm.

EDIT: -
Getting this error as well even though I have location.json file in my static folder

> GET http://localhost:3000/static/location.json 404 (Not Found)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: please show the content of location.json

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine It's extracted from takeout.google.com. I assume it should be fine.

Comment: the problem is in that json

Comment: You should try `fetch('/static/location.json',`. Check the network tab in the developer tools to see the request and it's response.